# Output rails coverage to console with rake

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, continuous-integration, code-coverage, travis-ci

My main idea is to have some code coverage reports after running test on Travis-CI.

At the moment I'm running tests with `rake travis`

```
task :travis do
  ["rspec spec", "rake cucumber"].each do |cmd|
    puts "Starting to run #{cmd}..."
    system("export DISPLAY=:99.0 && bundle exec #{cmd}")
    raise "#{cmd} failed!" unless $?.exitstatus == 0
  end
end
```

Now I think that the coverage can be outputted after tests into console, but all the coverage gems I've seen generate html pages as a result. Any ideas anyone?

Comment: Have you looked at the `coveralls` gem?

Comment: @alxndr on rubygems is says "since November 15, 2012". Looks like it was after my question :)

Answer (score 3):

You can play with the data returned by `rake stats`.

And here's the implementation if you want to do it yourself https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/master/railties/lib/rails/code_statistics.rb. In that case I recommend you create your own task.

Comment: Thank you, `rake stats` is an interesting thing. But can I somehow get the coverage data, for example from _somlecov_